# vlookup does not show date search

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to vlookup a date in a range of text, numbers, dates. vlookup search for number days of a given date, tried to change the number to date, but it does not work.

my formula is `=vlookup(date(2022,7,5),A:C,1,false)` for the below table. and it should show value `text5`.

```
  |  A         B         C
---------------------------
1 | text1   7/1/2022    001
2 | text2   7/2/2022    002
3 | text3   7/3/2022    003
4 | text4   7/4/2022    004
5 | text5   7/5/2022    005
```

It shows `#N/A` and the Error message was `Did not find value '44747' in VLOOKUP evaluation.`

I thought it was days and I need to change it to date format. to be `=vlookup(to_date(date(2022,7,5)),A:C,1,false)`. the same problem.

Comment: It should return `text5` not `text1`.

Comment: @Harun24hr you are right?

Comment: Try my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

`VLOOKUP()` will not work in this case, because `VLOOKUP()` always search on first column and your first column is text field and dates are on second column. So, use `INDEX()/MATCH()` instead. Try-

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(DATE(2022,7,5),B:B,0))
```

Also `FILTER()`, `QUERY()` functions will work in your case.

[image]

Comment: appreicate this, how can I match more than 1 column, like date and number 7/5/2022 and 5

Comment: Then use `=Filter(A:A,B:B=Date(2022,7,5),C:C=5)`